# sendmail configuration on ubuntu

Tags: sendmail

I am quite new to linux and trying to configure sendmail on my ubuntu box. Is there a way to configure it, so that it works "like" SMTP server? I did some search of course, but most of the posts configure sendmail for a website, in my case I just want to make it possible to send/receive emails to/from "world" as to say.

Comment: Have you tried any?

Comment: I ran the installation and tried to send emails from terminal, but it didnt work. So I looked into the logs, and apparently my /etc/hosts wasn't specified properly, after editting that I mamaged to send emails. But still not sure how to receive emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way to easily send mails from Ubuntu is by using the default mail transfer agent (MTA) provided, namely `postfix` (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix). It is also easier to configure than `sendmail`.

If you are looking for a off-the-shelf solution that sets everything up, you can try iRedMail (http://iredmail.org), although I would recommend installing it first in a virtual machine and testing it out. I don't know what side-effects it might have when installing on a desktop version of Ubuntu.